Is there a way to reuse AEM policy styleGroups?
I'm starting working with AEM style System and I'm facing a challenge regarding reusability. I have a ColumnControl which has more than one column, and I need to offer authors several styles for the columns – which I've already implemented through a policy linked to the columns.
<policy_col
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/policy/policy"
    components="[...]">
    <cq:styleGroups jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <style1
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq:styleGroupLabel="1">
            <cq:styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                ...
            </cq:styles>
        </style1>
        <style2
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq:styleGroupLabel="2">
            <cq:styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                ...
            </cq:styles>
        </style2>

But each column needs to allow different components, which means each column needs to have a different policy. But I wouldn't like to have to repeat all the styles for both policies:
<policy_col1
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/policy/policy"
    components="[...]">
    <cq:styleGroups jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <style1
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq:styleGroupLabel="1">
            <cq:styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                ...
            </cq:styles>
        </style1>
        <style2
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq:styleGroupLabel="2">
            <cq:styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                ...
            </cq:styles>
        </style2>
    </cq:styleGroups>
</policy_col1>
<policy_col2
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/policy/policy"
    components="[... different list]">
    <cq:styleGroups jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <style1
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq:styleGroupLabel="1">
            <cq:styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                ...
            </cq:styles>
        </style1>
        <style2
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq:styleGroupLabel="2">
            <cq:styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                ...
            </cq:styles>
        </style2>
    </cq:styleGroups>
</policy_col2>

Is there any way I can link one policy to an already defined anywhere cq:styleGroups?
